# Google Maps API 3 - Type error: a is undefined

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to dynamically load geocodes from a json file here http://debug-gotfed.admin.zope.net/bataviaeats/at/dev_remote_content

I'm getting a "Type Error: a is undefined." What am I missing?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Global

  var infowindow;
  var markers_img = 'http://gotfed.in/!/assets/global_images/got-fed-in-marker.png';
  var infoCloseIcon = 'images/close.png';
  var infoCloseMargin = '4px 4px 2px 2px';

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(58, 16),
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    $.each(locations, function(i, data) {
      console.log(data.geocode);
      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data.geocode);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          map: map,
          icon: markers_img
        });
      console.log(marker);
      // marker.setMap(map);
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
```

Comment: the error is forced by te missing `zoom`-property of the map, the map hasn't been instanciated successfully.

Comment: Thank you. Adding a zoom property cleared the error. Now, onto why the markers aren't appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all who answered. This is the final working code with additions for Infoboxes. I *did* have to turn the split geocode data into numbers. You can view this in real-time @ http://gotfed.in/fredericksburg-va

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  // Global
  var map;
  var infowindow;
  var markers_img = 'http://gotfed.in/!/assets/global_images/got-fed-in-marker.png';
  var infoCloseIcon = 'http://gotfed.in/!/assets/global_images/close.png';
  var infoCloseMargin = '4px 4px 2px 2px';
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    // create markers
    $.each(locations, function(i, data) {

      var geocode = data.geocode.split(',');
      var geo1 = parseFloat(geocode[0]);
      var geo2 = parseFloat(geocode[1]);
      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(geo1,geo2);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          map: map,
          icon: markers_img,
          title: data.business_name
        });
      bounds.extend(position);
      var id = "info" + i;
      console.log(id);
      var infobox = new InfoBox({
         content: document.getElementById(id),
         disableAutoPan: false,
         maxWidth: 150,
         pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
         zIndex: null,
         boxStyle: {width: "280px"},
        closeBoxMargin: infoCloseMargin,
        closeBoxURL: infoCloseIcon,
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infobox.open(map, this);
        map.panTo(position);
      });
    });

    // set Bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    // Keep map centered
    var center;
    function calculateCenter() {
      center = map.getCenter()
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
      calculateCenter();
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
      map.setCenter(center);
    });

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 16):

You are either having the firebug console open when loading the page or one of firefox extension clogging the downloading, making the browser can not get full script from google.

Solution: turn of firebug console, if that's not the case, then try disable the extensions individually see what conflict.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my hours.

Comment: So is this a Firebugbug? Is there any discussion about this issue, for example the cause?

Comment: It also happened to me with Firefox's built-in console opened.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the v3 for example as release version ,and it will work with firebug and any other extension

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```

all credits goes here :
[Google Maps API: TypeError: a is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691295/google-maps-api-typeerror-a-is-undefined)

Answer (score 4):

The [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) constructor takes two arguments. This is wrong:

```
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data.geocode);
```

If data.geocode is already a google.maps.LatLng object, just use it.  If it is a JSON object with lat and lng properties, then you have to pass those separately into the constructor:

```
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data.geocode.lat, data.geocode.lng);
```

code for your specific data:

```
      var geocode=data.geocode.split(',');
      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(geocode[0],geocode[1]);
```

Comment: An example of "data.geocode" is "42.981718,-77.992174". I did split it into two properties before and it still didn't work.

Comment: See Dr.Molle's addition to my answer (which still applies).  A google.maps.LatLng takes two _numbers_ as arguments, not a string containing a comma.  You didn't provide any details about the contents of you JSON in your question.

Comment: And in fact it's two **Numbers**. Splitting a string produces two **Strings**, which may not work reliably through all API versions either.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I did split the string into numbers and that helped. `code    var geocode = data.geocode.split(',');
    var geo1 = parseFloat(geocode[0]);
    var geo2 = parseFloat(geocode[1]);
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(geo1,geo2);`