# Google Maps API: TypeError: a is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have searched this problem all over the web and none of them seem to give me any resolution. I have a simple script to just display the map of South Africa.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge, chrome=1" />
<title>Map Test</title>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<style>
#map-canvas {
    height: 300px;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas" class="map_canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize()
    {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-29.09958,26.18434),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            }
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I keep on getting the same error over and over. I have even tried on a different server.

[image]

Please help

Comment: I could not replicate this issue using Chrome 44 ~ 45. I even tried Firefox and there's no error.

Comment: @KimHonoridez, the issue does not seem to affect Chrome.  The error is intermittent in Firefox 41.0.1.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I've also seen this error often in the last days, there seems to be an issue with the experimental API-version.

Load the release-version instead(basically you should always load the release-version in production)

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&v=3"></script>
```

Comment: I am surprised that Google serves the experimental (ie. unstable) version by default.  However, that is often the case: "If you do not explicitly specify a version, you will receive the experimental version by default. Google Maps API for Work customers who specify a client ID will receive the release version by default."  (From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)

Comment: The answer will load the latest "release" version of the v3 API.  For some applications, it may be more appropriate to request a specific version (ex. 3.21).  See Google's "Best Practices" for more guidance: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#best-practices

Comment: @Dr.Molle, "the sensor parameter is no longer required.": https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks a ton. This problem was causing Firebug to be extremely slow and regularly freezing - making debugging a nightmare.  Using "v=3" fixed that.

Comment: MAN! i've going craze with this... i've been using the same code for over a year, and suddenly new API keys wouldn't work.

Comment: The map popups entirely stopped working on my site, out of the blue last week. Turned out I just needed to add the version and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps started to through errors when loading the script and on touch events. I'm using it for a cordova application on Android and iOS.[image]

These are the errors I get but changing the load version didn't solve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&v=3.21&libraries=geometry,places"></script>
```

Comment: I've just realised I was loading GMaps async when the device was going online, and there I had the incorrect URL. Here you go, my Saturday gone in me being stupid.

Comment: Good job in solving it and thanks for posting your findings. Always good to help others

Answer (score 1):

Version 3.30+ is affected of this problem if there is a global var called `Map`.

ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEYHERE&v=3&callback=init" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        Map.go();
    }
    var Map = {
        go: function() {
            console.log("start engine");
        }
    };
</script>
```

We got this error:

> TypeError: a.prototype is undefined

Renaming `window.Map` then everything goes fine.