# Google Maps error Cannot read property 'prototype': Exact same website on different URL's but only on one the map is displayed

Tags: google-maps

I have a website using Google Maps for displaying the location on a contact form. In my testlocation and on other production sites I do have the map displayed and no error message comes up. However, today I have published two websites and on both of the live sites, the google maps are not working. I do get an error in the console saying: cannot read property 'prototype' in the common.js file of Google Maps. Below one of both websites.

Google Maps working on the following URL:

http://doopsuiker.test-d-care.be/Contact

Google Maps not working on the following URL:

http://doopsuikerbeveren.be/Contact

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried changing the version as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691295/google-maps-api-typeerror-a-is-undefined/32691543)

Comment: Thx for your reply... I just modified our code to retrieve version 3 but the result is still the same (view page source). Besides this, the two URL's above point to the same web application but only have distinct A-records. Furthermore, in general we have one web application with multiple databases and by means of the domainname we show different content. For all domains the gmap is working except for the ones I have set up yesterday. But they all share the same code base. One more thing, currently we have not used API key for using gmaps, but I thought this is not required. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Simply setting up an API-key and using it fixed the this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

your must activate google Mpas Javascript Api:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard/